# Creating an API proxy for an Azure Static Web App

Tags: reactjs, flask, azure-web-app-service, restful-url

I have a static website (React SPA) hosted as an Azure Static Web Application, I also have a flask backend that is hosted online, is there a way for me to add the URL of the backend so that all requests will go there? (Similar to adding a proxy to package.json in React)

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes

Comment: You can provide more information to help you better. ^-^